# Is getActionBar() supposed to return null?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm trying to make a Toolbar in a fragment an Action Bar. This is what I do:

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sourceitem_list, viewGroup, false);

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) mListener).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

where `mListener` is the Activity that contains the fragment.

However, if I have the following straight after

```
    ActionBar actionbar = ((AppCompatActivity) mListener).getActionBar();
```

`actionbar` is null. How come it's still null even when the ActionBar has been set in the previous line already? Otherwise, what's a good way to set the property of the newly set ActionBar?

Thanks

Comment: `.getSupportActionBar();` used

Comment: Right. How are the two different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use `AppCompatActivity` you use the `supportActionBar` and therefor you need to use `getSupportActionBar()`.

This supports older android versions than the normal `Activity` and `ActionBar`.